# Socket.IO: How to communicate/exchange data between socket.on() event in the same server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, socket.io

I have certain line of code written under one `socket.on` event which is being called from client side to get the data using callback mechanism.
Is it possible to communicate between two `socket.on` event and exchange the data using callback within the same server and same file ?

For. e.g. A normal flow between client and server:

```
socket.emit('init',data,function(callbackFromServer)) //from client
          |      ^
          |      | server respond through callback to client
          V      |
socket.on('init',function(data, callback){/*....*/});  // to server
```

I want to implement same case, but within server itself between two `socket.on()` event, to exchange the data. i.e.:

```
                         client  
                          |  ^
                          V  |
      socket.on('someEvent',function(data,callback1){/*....*/}) // some.js
                          |  ^
                          V  | // <-- I want to achieve this
      socket.on('init',function(data,callback2){/*.....*/})     // some.js
```

Is it possible to achieve this, by any approach ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood the use-case completely, but if you just want to call the other function, why don't you use variables to reference those functions? You can then call them whenever you want.

```
var someEventFn = function(data, callback1) {
        initFn(data, function(result) {
            // here you have the result from the init method
        });
    },
    initFn = function(data, callback2) {
        // some js
    };

socket.on('someEvent', someEventFn);
socket.on('init', initFn);
```

Then you can call `initFn` from inside `someEventFn` while still allowing it to be called in the socket.on event. Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Create another socket io client in server side, and then call the function using that client.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:port');
socket.on('connect', function () {  
  socket.emit('another function', { param1: 'value1' });
});
```